# Building up AST from a function with more than one returns for llvm

Tags: llvm

For example I have this function:

```
def max(a,b) {
   if(a < b) return b;
   if(a > b) return a;
}
```

I am curious how to parse this into an AST.
If I understand this well then the node of it's body should return a ReturnInst*.

But in my AST this body is contained by two nodes (as expressions), one for the first if and another one for the other one.

Is there some trick or the design is wrong to begin with?

Edit: I've just tough out a might-be-a-solution:

1. CreateAlloca at the begin of the body.
2. CreateStore and jump to the end label at every return.
3. At the end label return the var.

Is it a good idea? And how to jump/goto with llvm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outlined solution with alloca+store+jump definitely works, if I'm understanding it correctly.  And yes, the LLVM optimizers will handle it just fine.  Alternatively, there isn't any restriction on the number of ret instructions in a given function.

Not sure what you're asking with generating a goto; if you've managed to write an if statement, it the same sort of br instruction you need at the end of one.  In general, running "clang -S -emit-llvm" over some simple code is a good technique to see how to generate simple constructs.  Also, "llc -march=cpp" is a good way to see how to build instructions in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the online demo: http://llvm.org/demo/ Type in the C or C++ for what you want to do and it will show you the LLVM output.

Comment: the demo page c++ backend is severely outdated, and renders code that won't work in recent versions of LLVM (3.0).. for this particular structure that doesn't matter though, but be aware of this when recommending people to rely on it for understanding the API